# Cannot find ansible.cfg after installation on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, ansible

My app installs `ansible==2.2.1.0` as part of its requirements and I'd like it to use a library I have in a specific location.
I try to find the ansible.cfg file but can't find it anywhere and not sure where it's best to be put.
I am using Mac OS.
EDIT:
I set up a config file at: `/Users/<myuser>/.ansible.cfg` and when I run the `ansible-playbook` with `-vvv` it shows:
Using `/Users/<myuser>/.ansible.cfg` as config file

But I am getting this errors and warnings for some reason:

```
[WARNING]: Host file not found: /etc/ansible/hosts

[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available

ERROR! conflicting action statements
```

Thanks!

Comment: See this answer on Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/975319/can-t-find-the-config-file-in-etc-ansible-on-mac-os-x

Comment: I tried everything I saw there but with no success. How can I check what configuration file the ansible-playbook is accessing before it's run

Comment: Use the `-vv` argument with `ansible` or `ansible-playbook` to see which config file is used. This was added in version 2 I believe.

Comment: The warnings and the error message you posted have nothing to do with `ansible.cfg`. Moreover, [Ansible code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.2/lib/ansible/parsing/mod_args.py#L0290) clearly shows you have not included the full error message. Even if for some reason the variables were empty, at least comma is hardcoded and should follow. The question in this form should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#configuration-file):

> Changes can be made and used in a configuration file which will be processed in the following order:
>
> - ANSIBLE_CONFIG (an environment variable)
> - ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
> - .ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
> - /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

That said, these locations need not be populated for *Ansible* to function. But you should ***look for them there***.

If your application is running *Ansible*, and you would like to specify the contents of the config, just create an `ansible.cfg` in the executing directory. If you are looking to manage the config, just look for them in that order and manage as you see fit. You could even create each of those files and *Ansible* will look for them. You may then determine which `ansible.cfg` is being used by adding the `-vv` argument to your `ansible` or `ansible-playbook` calls.

The warnings and errors you are seeing are unrelated to the *Ansible* config not being found.

```
[WARNING]: Host file not found: /etc/ansible/hosts
```

When you call `ansible` or `ansible-playbook`, add `--inventory path/to/your/inventory`. This will also resolve the warning below.

```
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available

ERROR! conflicting action statements
```

This is typically caused by having multiple module calls within a single task item. Just split them up:

```
- name: make some files
  file: state=directory dest=/etc/foo
  file: src=foo/bar dest=/etc/foo/bar
```

Should be

```
- name: create a dir
  file: state=directory dest=/etc/foo

- name: create a file
  file: src=foo/bar dest=/etc/foo/bar
```

Comment: Hi, so this is the yml I am trying to run. I managed to run it before, multiple times. I feel there may be some Ansible configuration I am missing because the file itself didn't change

http://pastebin.com/Gi0eL3sh

Comment: That does not look like Ansible. I believe what you are attempting to accomplish with the "custom_attributes" key is defining Ansible vars, which should be done in a `vars` section (see [the docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variables-defined-in-a-playbook)). The rest of the contents of the "tasks" list don't make any sense as that list should contain Ansible module calls, and should be list items, not `key: value` pairs which would be a part of a YAML object. Please refer to [the getting started docs](https://www.ansible.com/get-started) for further correction.